# Defining function or class to browse and list multiple directories with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to create a function or class that has the proper formatting to create a text label, entry field, and button. The button would allow me to browse through my directory and populate the entry field with the chosen directory. The code I have allows me to do most of this, however the directory is always populated in the last entry field instead of the one the button refers to.

I am new to tkinter and GUIs so apologies if this is a simple solution, I assume the problem is with `root.name.set` referring to the function that was called last.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def askdirectory():
  dirname = filedialog.askdirectory()
  root.name.set(dirname)


def dirField(root, label, rowNum):
    text = StringVar()
    text.set(label)
    dirText = Label(root, textvariable = text, height =4)
    dirText.grid(row = rowNum, column = 1)

    dirBut = Button(root, text = 'Browse', command = askdirectory)
    dirBut.grid(row = rowNum, column = 3)

    root.name = StringVar()
    adDir = Entry(root,textvariable = root.name, width = 100)
    adDir.grid(row = rowNum, column = 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('1000x750')

    adText = "Select directory of Ads"
    userText = "Select directory of User credentials"

    adField = dirField(root, adText, 1)
    userField = dirField(root, userText, 2)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should realise that you need to have each `Entry` have its own `textvariable`. Otherwise they will overlap. Have a look at my code, which should get you going.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

path = [None, None] # Fill it with the required number of filedialogs

def askdirectory(i):
    dirname = filedialog.askdirectory()
    path[i].set(dirname)


def dirField(root, label, rowNum, i):
    dirText = Label(root, text=label)
    dirText.grid(row=rowNum, column=0)

    dirBut = Button(root, text='Browse', command=lambda: askdirectory(i))
    dirBut.grid(row=rowNum, column=2)

    path[i] = StringVar()
    adDir = Entry(root, textvariable=path[i], width=50)
    adDir.grid(row=rowNum, column=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    adText = "Select directory of Ads"
    userText = "Select directory of User credentials"

    adField = dirField(root, adText, 0, 0)
    userField = dirField(root, userText, 1, 1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this fixed my problem. You are right, I didn't know the correct way to link the `askdirectory` function with the `dirfield` without it getting too messy - your solution works wonderfully.